# Wordpress custom pages relationship custom url rewrite (giving up)

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, parent-child, custom-pages

I’ve created 2 custom posts (post types), and I’m trying to make the urls right.

custom page 1 "products" contains products
custom page 2 "productlist" contains lists of products picked from the products.

When you create a productlist you can pick products from custom page 1.
The relationship works fine (using ACF pro plugin) and products are showing up right on all pages, It's just wrong urls.

**FILES**
archive-productlist.php
single-productlist.php
single-product.php

**current url stucture:**
example.com/productlist/some-list
example.com/product/some-product

**should be:**
example.com/produclist/some-list/some-product

index.php?post_type=productlist&productlist=some-list-clicked&product=some-product-clicked

The url is good until the link to the product is clicked and goes back to
example.com/product/some-product

**functions.php**

product page should be something like:

```
'has_archive'         => 'productlist',
‘rewrite’ => array(‘slug’=>’productlist/%thelist%/product’, ‘with_front’=> false),
```

productlist page is currently:

```
‘rewrite’ => array(‘slug’=>’productlist’,’with_front’=> false),
```

I've given up after days of head-scratching and searching, so can anyone explain how to fix this?